# Primefaces inplace editor always updates backing bean

Tags: primefaces, inplace-editing

I have

```
<p:inplace editor="true">
    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.foo}"/>
</p:inplace>
...
<p:commandButton value="BarAction" actionListener="#{myBean.barAction}"/>
```

In setFoo body I'm persisting updated foo value so I want to have it executed only in user clicks on save icon of inplace editor.

The problem is that MyBean.setFoo(...) is always fired even if inplace editor was not activated. For example if I click on [BarAction] button the setFoo gets executed too. I would expect that setFoo get fired only if default save button of inplace editor is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your commandButton the property `process="@this"`. By default the commandButton will process the entire form.